# cambiar el translate3d con un click JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

**Amigos es que quiero saber cómo puedo cambiar el translate3d cada vez que doy un click por ejemplo
lista.style.transform = 'translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)';
Así sería el translate cuando esta por defecto
Pero cuando le doy click el translate quede asi y aumente cada 150px
lista.style.transform = 'translate3d(-150px, 0px, 0px)';

esto es para lograr una función de un slide
estaria muy agradecido de quien me pueda ayudar con mi problema muchas gracias
como el que esta aqui => https://yourplanyourplanet.sustainability.google/food-pillar/amount
**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mira no se si es lo mas elegante que escribí en mi vida, pero creo que hace el truco que vos necesitas.

```
let contenedor = document.getElementById('container')
        
        let valorActual = contenedor.style.transform

        if(valorActual.length>0)
        {
            let valores = valorActual.split("(")[1].split(",")
                    
            let xPos = parseInt(valores[0])-150
            let yPos = parseInt(valores[1])
            let zPos = parseInt(valores[2])

            contenedor.style.transform = "translate3d(" + xPos + "px, " + yPos + "px, " + zPos + "px)"
        }
        else
        {
            contenedor.style.transform = "translate3d(0px,0px,0px)"         
        }
```

La parte del else la escribí porque yo no tengo translate3d aplicado, pero si vos lo tenes desde el principio podes obviar todo el If

Comment: muchas gracias amigo me sirvió mucho eres un grande gracias, tienes alguna idea de cómo puedo mejorar con javaScript  te lo agradecería mucho

Comment: No hay de que Jesus!, hay muchos cursos y mucha documentación online, yo empecé hace poco, hice un curso online, y mucha mucha lectura! Leer acá, preguntar, e intentar responder preguntas ayuda mucho también =)